# Perl - If system command fails or runs for too long how can I stop it or run another system call?

Tags: perl, error-handling, runtime-error, system

I have a perl script that executes many other scripts at certain times.

Once in a while these other script may hang permanently or outright fail, but there is no current way to tell if these other scripts do so.

How can I implement a way to check if a script either runs for too long (so the user can take action) or outright fails. The plan being an email can be sent to the appropriate user notifying them.

Example of the system call below:

```
elsif ($job_type eq 'script') { 
    system("perl $job_dir/$job_args > $work_dir/$job_name.out 2> work_dir/$job_name.err");
}
```

Comment: See [alarm](http://p3rl.org/alarm) and [fork](http://p3rl.org/fork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html):

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
    alarm 120;   # 2 Minute timeout

    system("perl $job_dir/$job_args > $work_dir/$job_name.out 2> work_dir/$job_name.err");

    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # Propagate unexpected errors

    # Timed out - Send out email to user
    ...

} else {
    # Successfully ran command.  Any cleanup here.
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Miller. What does this script do if the system call either fails to start or just fails during execution?

Comment: The code that I've provided only handles the case of the system command taking too long for whatever reason.  For additional error checking, you'd have to add more code.  Perhaps checking the return value from the system call?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the CPAN module `IPC::Run`. It packages up a lot of the fiddly details for you. Its documentation is pretty bad, but once you get through enough of it to understand how to do things it's very convenient.